# Basic Python function for even numbers in a list

Tags: python

This is the problem I am working on:

1. Write a function that accepts a List of numbers as an argument.
2. Return a new List that includes the only the even numbers.

Here is what I have:

```py
def only_evens(list1):
    evens = []
    for number in list1:
        if (number % 2 == 0):
            evens.append(number)
    return evens

print(only_evens(list1))
only_evens([11, 20, 42, 97])
```

I get the following error: NameError: name 'list1' is not defined

My thought process for solving it was:

1. Create an empty array inside the function to store the numbers
2. Write a for loop to check if the number is even
3. If it's even, append the number to `evens`
4. Return the `evens` array that should be full of the even numbers, and print it
5. Check using random numbers. (I used 11, 20, 42, 97)

I know there are easier methods to solve this than what I am doing, but I am trying to do this by hand to get a solid foundation in functions.

Comment: print(only_evens(list1)) is placed wrongly. list1 is not defined outside the function.

Answer (score 2):

In your `print` statement, you call `only_evens` with an undefined variable named: `list1`.

```py
def only_evens(list1) :
    evens = []
    for number in list1:
        if (number % 2 == 0):
            evens.append(number)
    return evens

# Create `list1` here in order to reference it as an argument to `only_evens`
list1 = [11, 20, 42, 97]

print(only_evens(list1))
```

Answer (score 2):

You're passing `list1` as argument to `only_evens()` in the `print()` function, but you haven't declared the `list1` anywhere.

Solving your problem with list comprehension would be more pythonic :)

```
def only_evens(list1):
    return [n for n in list1 if n%2 == 0]

list1 = [7, 4, 15, 33]  # This was lacking in your code
print(only_evens(list1))  # This is where the error occurred
only_evens([11, 20, 42, 97])
```

Comment: You may want to add that `print()`

Comment: @tevemadar Done.

Comment: For loops are perfectly pythonic

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, but when you have such a great feature as list comprehensions available, you want to use it. This is a perfect use case for one.